# Django annotate with complex value

Tags: django, django-queryset

Is it possible to annotate with complex value?

Like if I have table

```
class Test(models.model):
   value = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('value'))

next = 5
import math
Test.objects.annotate(new_field=math.sqrt(next-value)/math.atan(value))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't pass math functions into `annotate()`.

If you want to do this calculation in `Test` model then create a method:

```
class Test(models.model):
    value = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('value'))

    def calc_value(self, next):
        return math.sqrt(next-self.value)/math.atan(self.value))

for t in Test.objects.all():
    print t.value. t.calc_value(5)
```

But if you want to use this calculation to order the queryset then you have to do the math at [SQL level](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#extra):

```
next = 5
Test.objects.extra(select={'new_field': 'SQRT(%d-value)/ATAN(value)' % next}) \
            .order_by('new_field'))
```

To filter the queryset by new field use `where` argument of the same `extra()` method:

```
Test.objects.extra(select={'new_field': 'SQRT(%d-value)/ATAN(value)' % next},
                   where=['new_field > 10'])
```

SQLite doesn't support math functions by default but with Postgres and MySQL this code should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I wanted. Is there any way to filter by this new_field ins where clause? Or I can apply filter method?

Comment: You have to use `extra(where=[...])`.  See the updated answer.

Comment: Fantastic. Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

[No, annotations can only be done on django aggregations.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/)

> Annotates each object in the QuerySet with the provided list of aggregate values (averages, sums, etc) that have been computed over the objects that are related to the objects in the QuerySet.